# Linear change in force of interest

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

The force of interest $\delta$(t) is 10% p.a. at the start of the year, 7% p.a. at the end of 9th month and 5% p.a. at the end of the year. $\delta$(t) is linear during the two periods before and after the end of 9th month.

In such scenario, how do I calculate the accumulated value at the end of the year, of a sum invested at the start of the year?

Basucally, how to account for a linear change in the force of interest?

I tried interpolation but it doesn't match the answer. Is there some other way?

Comment: did you account for the time each was in effect, also is it simple, or compound interest ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Its compound interest. How to account for time exactly?

Comment: my research actually has it as continuous compounding technically. but if simple compounding, if 10% is APY raise 1.1( whole plus 10%)  to the exponent 9/12 ( 9 months of 12 months in a year) etc. if APR multiply 0.10 by 1/12 and add 1 to ot, followed by raising it to the ninth power.